# How to use Trino/Presto to connect to Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, presto, trino

My configuration file is as follows:

```
connector.name=elasticsearch
elasticsearch.host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
elasticsearch.port=9200
elasticsearch.default-schema-name=default
elasticsearch.scroll-size=5000
elasticsearch.scroll-timeout = 30s
elasticsearch.request-timeout = 60s
elasticsearch.connect-timeout = 60s
elasticsearch.max-retry-time = 30s
elasticsearch.node-refresh-interval = 1s
elasticsearch.max-http-connections=50
elasticsearch.http-thread-count=4
elasticsearch.auth.user=xxx
elasticsearch.auth.password=xxx
elasticsearch.security=PASSWORD
elasticsearch.tls.enabled=true
elasticsearch.tls.keystore-path=/opt/pem/http.pem
elasticsearch.tls.truststore-path=/opt/pem/elastic-certificates.pem
```

After using the certificate, it keeps saying that the connection is refused. When tls is not turned on and only uses password authentication, it keeps saying that the connection is closed. How do I set it up? A configuration file has been provided, can you tell me what the problem is?

The specific error is as follows:

```
2021-07-19T17:45:17.541+0800    INFO    main    io.trino.metadata.StaticCatalogStore    -- Loading catalog etc/catalog/elasticsearch.properties --
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       PROPERTY                               DEFAULT     RUNTIME                            DESCRIPTION
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       jmx.base-name                          ----        ----
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.backoff-init-delay       500.00ms    500.00ms                           Initial delay to wait between backpressure retries
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.backoff-max-delay        20.00s      20.00s                             Maximum delay to wait between backpressure retries
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.connect-timeout          1.00s       60.00s                             Elasticsearch connect timeout
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.default-schema-name      default     default                            Default schema name to use
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.host                     ----        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.http-thread-count        4           4                                  Number of threads handling HTTP connections to Elasticsearch
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.ignore-publish-address   false       false
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.tls.keystore-password    [REDACTED]  [REDACTED]
2021-07-19T17:45:18.189+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.tls.keystore-path        ----        /opt/pem/http.pem
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.max-http-connections     25          50                                 Maximum number of persistent HTTP connections to Elasticsearch
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.max-retry-time           30.00s      30.00s                             Maximum timeout in case of multiple retries
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.node-refresh-interval    1.00m       1.00s                              How often to refresh the list of available Elasticsearch nodes
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.port                     9200        9200
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.request-timeout          10.00s      60.00s                             Elasticsearch request timeout
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.scroll-size              1000        5000                               Scroll batch size
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.scroll-timeout           1.00m       30.00s                             Scroll timeout
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.security                 ----        PASSWORD
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.tls.enabled              false       true
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.tls.truststore-path      ----        /opt/pem/elastic-certificates.pem
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.tls.truststore-password  [REDACTED]  [REDACTED]
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.tls.verify-hostnames     true        true
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.auth.password            [REDACTED]  [REDACTED]
2021-07-19T17:45:18.190+0800    INFO    main    Bootstrap       elasticsearch.auth.user                ----        xxx
2021-07-19T17:45:19.969+0800    INFO    main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle starting...
2021-07-19T17:45:19.970+0800    INFO    main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle startup complete
2021-07-19T17:45:19.971+0800    INFO    main    io.trino.metadata.StaticCatalogStore    -- Added catalog elasticsearch using connector elasticsearch --
2021-07-19T17:45:19.974+0800    INFO    main    io.trino.security.AccessControlManager  Using system access control default
2021-07-19T17:45:20.019+0800    INFO    main    io.trino.server.Server  ======== SERVER STARTED ========
2021-07-19T17:45:20.944+0800    ERROR   NodeRefresher   io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient        Error refreshing nodes
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Connection refused
        at io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient.doRequest(ElasticsearchClient.java:803)
        at io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient.fetchNodes(ElasticsearchClient.java:381)
        at io.trino.plugin.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient.refreshNodes(ElasticsearchClient.java:185)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: How is this relevant to Scala?

Comment: Many people who use scala are engaged in big data-related work, elasticsearch and presto are big data-related technologies.So I added the scala language when asking questions.

Comment: Please do not add misleading tags. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Since the error says message is "connection refused", it means that elastic search node is refusing this connection. It can be for too many reasons. You need to investigate the possible causes 1-by-1. First check whether this trino-node can actually talk to the elastic node at that particular port by using a telnet client. Once that succeeds, try using an elastic search client to connet to elastic search. If that succeeds then compare, if there is something missing in trino config when compared to your es-client. Check for version compatibility as well.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and last solved this problem under the guidance of community netizens. Need to add `elasticsearch.ignore-publish-address=true`  in the elasticsearch.properties  file